# Could not install package 'EfSchemaCompare.EF6 1.0.0'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I searched online for '**Deploying an Entity Framework Database into Production**'
and i found `EfSchemaCompare.EF6 1.0.0 package` created by Jon Smith very useful.
But When I tried to install it with Nuget Package Manager Console, it gives the following error :

[image: Error Image after running command in package manager console]

Thank you

Comment: Which version of framework is your project using? Most likely the package needs newer version than you are using.

Comment: does upgrading the .net version fixes the setup issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NuGet package includes a [folder structure for .net 4.5.1](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks),

[image]

targeting .net framework 4.5.1:

```
<frameworkAssemblies>
  <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Core" targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5.1" />
</frameworkAssemblies>
```

but according to the message, your Project is targeting .net 4.5. So open the properties of your project and change the Targetframework to 4.5.1

[image]

Comment: thank you. I was confused about whether I should Upgrade framework or Downgrade